# Word for a playing card that isn't a Joker?

Tags: single-word-requests

> *A deck of playing cards usually consists of two jokers and fifty-two _____s.*

Is there a name for this that’s better than “cards with numerical values”?

Comment: To me, “cards with numerical values” just means the **2** through **10** ("pip" cards, to the great unwashed). Although the Ace has a numerical value, it's usually included with the Jack (Knave), Queen, and King as a "court" card.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How about *suit cards*?

The jokers are distinguished by not having a suit. And this phrase has been used for exactly this purpose (Google [*fifty-two suit cards*](https://www.google.com/#q=%22fifty-two+suit+cards%22)).

Comment: Low fruit, given all the comments, but clearly an upvote ;-)

Comment: This page is now the top result for the linked search. I guess that makes it official. :P

Answer (score 5):

A deck of cards consists of fifty-two playing cards plus two jokers.  Jokers, whether there be one or two, are not counted among the playing cards.  Jokers only appeared in decks on or around 1860 when a version of euchre became popular in America that involved a third bower, which is why there are only two jokers and not four.  Even the name *joker* is a permutation of *euchre*.  The joker is not standard fare in card games, not even in euchre.

Short Answer:  The word for a playing card that isn't a joker is "playing card."  Jokers aren't playing cards.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_card

Comment: While it is possible to make this argument, it is unhelpful as an answer to the question, and demonstrably false in real life. The cited article does not support the claim that "Jokers aren't playing cards", and indeed a different Wikipedia article [Joker (playing card)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joker_%28playing_card%29) begins "The Joker is a playing card found in most modern card decks". I fear that the actual answer to the question is that there is no common answer to the question.

Comment: @Colin Fine : The article doesn't say that jokers are playing cards.  It says that there are fifty-two playing cards in a deck, twelve face cards and forty non-face cards, or number cards.  Also, when you buy a deck of cards, it says on the package, contains fifty-two playing cards plus two jokers.  That said, I tend to agree with you that there's no real common or even prescriptive answer to this question.  I almost didn't even answer this question because I'm not entirely sure it's on-topic.  In fact, I'm all but convinced it's off-topic.  Is there an SE Gaming site?

Comment: @Colin Fine: I think in practice *most* native speakers would be happy to endorse Benjamin's position here (jokers aren't normally counted as ***playing** cards*). But for the ultra-finicky, here are half-a-dozen references to [*52 **suit** cards*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%2252+suit+cards%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Exactly: I've heard *suit cards* used, and it is immediately obvious (and recognised as excluding jokers). Benjamin has a point, but *suit card* is the best answer. P.S. Do you happen to play Bridge?

Comment: @Cerberus: I haven't played bridge for many years, but I did used to enjoy it. You certainly wouldn't want to accidentally leave the Jokers in when dealing a hand of Bridge (it might leave you *vulnerable* to accusations that you didn't know the difference between Bridge and Snap! :)

Comment: @Cerberus Bridge is a game with four jokers, although they're usually called by the compass points.

Comment: In Canasta ([see Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canasta)), the Jokers **are** playing cards.

Comment: They are cards made to play with, thus playing cards.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Haha, indeed! I rarely play it either, and I've never played it on a regular basis, but I do like the game very much.

Comment: @deadrat: Depends on the company! At least you can slam them once in a while.

Comment: @Cerberus: Many, *many* moons ago, four of us sat round a card table in a small tent playing Bridge while smoking weed, in an otherwise deserted camping site. The wind gradually got stronger over a couple of hours, but we were so engrossed/out of it no-one really noticed until the whole tent blew away. Then we had to walk about a mile to the nearest village - and I kid you not, the wind was so strong we were leaning into it at almost 45° to maintain traction and make slow headway. But we all hung on to our cards, and we finished the hand when we arrived safely at the pub!

Comment: Like @TripeHound stated, the Joker is a playing card in Canastra and probably several other games.

Comment: I would probably say "standard playing cards"...

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Hah, well done! Very English.

Comment: In poker, the opposite of wild is natural.

Answer (score 1):

..and fifty-two non-jokers :). Hehe, and why not say 'and fifty-two regular cards'.

Or: 
A deck of playing cards usually consists of fifty-two cards and often two extra joker cards.

Or:
A deck of playing cards usually consists of fifty-four cards.

And then split it out in the rest of the story.

Answer (score 1):

A [natural hand](http://www.pokernews.com/pokerterms/natural.htm) is a hand without any wild cards. So perhaps you can say non-wild cards are "natural cards".